# Cursor position is changing while any new new value entered in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jsp

Definition: I have a textbox which has maxlength of 11 characters. If I try to enter value in the middle of that textbox, cursor position is moved automatically to end position. Could you please help me to set cursor position fixed.

Note: Function is used for textbox allows only alphanumeric value.

Here the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
//function for alphanumberic validation
function alphaNumericOnly(i){
if(i.value != null) 
    {
        i.value = i.value.replace(/[^\w]+/g, ''); 

    }
    }
</script>
<input type="text" maxlength="11" id="policyOrBondNum" onkeyup="alphaNumericOnly(this);" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The cursor position changes because you bludgeon the value, replacing it with a new one. (It has nothing to do with `maxlength`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How do I fixed that cursor position? Could you please help me?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I have a js funciton executed at one textbox OnKeyUp event.

I enter some value in a textbox.
If I place my cursor in the middle of the string and I add a char, the cursor moves at the end of the string.

Is there a way to avoid the cursor moving at the end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
<input type="text" maxlength="11" id="policyOrBondNum" onkeyup="alphaNumericOnly(this);" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 50px;"/>
```

Comment: you can change the padding value to set it properly or can use CSS as well!!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to fixed the position of the cursor.This change is not working dude.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: if i have understood you right, try the edited one, else please elaborate the question

Comment: @Razor I have a js funciton executed at one textbox OnKeyUp event. I enter some value in a textbox. If I place my cursor in the middle of the string and I add a char, the cursor moves at the end of the string. Is there a way to avoid the cursor moving at the end of the string? –

Comment: I forgot about the JS, i'm really sorry!! Now i understood your problem. Its goin to the end because on keyup event it is processing the entire string and leaving the cursor at the end. I'm trying to solve it. I'll get back when i find the answer!!

Comment: @Gareth HI Gareth goodevening could you please help me in this issue. I saw your answer related to similar kind of question. But I cant understand could please help me to fix this issue.